# How to push user1 location tracking info to user 2 on ios

Tags: java, ios, spring, spring-boot, react-native

I need a good design to read the location from a user1 iOS and send it to user2 iOS.

1. How I should send this to the backend, using rest APIs?
2. The location data pushed to server should be at 20sec interval or more?
3. Once the location info is with backend how it should push that to user2, badges or a poll from the app?

Please suggest.

Comment: anybody would suggest a good industry practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, first step is to send the information to the backend, in that case you only need a rest api exposed with a method that can receive the POST.

Second step is send the information to the second device. Here you can implement in two ways:

1. Push notification, you can use tools from the iOS libraries to send the information to the second device and the application will use this information.

Read more about this here: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/learn-master-%EF%B8%8F-ios-remote-push-notifications-in-2018-in-under-10-minutes-825ca6bee092

2. Second option, it is to implement a websocket, your second device will be connected with a web protocol to receive information from the server. This is a solution for real time systems, every thing you need to send will be received by the target in milliseconds.